# Will the Ubuntu installer automatically detect other versions of Linux?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I recently purchased a computer off a friend and decided to set it up as a work station at home. To that end, my supervisor and I spent the day getting Mageia (Red Hat distribution) installed along with our research group's software. We had first tried to install the software in Ubuntu, but the software was designed a long time ago and does not appear to be comparable (at least not easily) with modern Ubuntu. In the process of installing Mageia, the Ubuntu install was overwritten. As of now, Mageia is installed on sda (120 GB ssd) with a swap partition, EFI partition, / partition and mounts sdb (1 TB ext 4 formatted hdd). I have a couple of other hard drives that I can install in the machine and would like to use one of them to dual boot Ubuntu.

My main reasons for wanting to do this are a) I know Debian a bit better than Red Hat b) Ubuntu has better community support than Mageia c) I would like to learn more about Linux and fool around with it, but don't want to accidently brick my work station.

My main question is if I will have to do anything special in the Ubuntu installation such that I will be able to dual boot to either operating system. I don't care if the Mageia boot loader is over written so long as the I can dual boot.

Edit:

As I feared, when I chose to install alongside Mageia, the install went fine until it reached the point of installing the boot loader. At this point the boot loader installer failed. If anyone could help me with this it would be greatly appreciated. The current hard drive configuration is as follows:

sda: 
1TB Mageia ext 4 partition mounted at /media

sdb:
200 MB EFI partition for the bootloader
12 GB swap space
100 GB ext 4 partition mounted at /

sdc:
2 TB ext 4 partition to be used as storage by Ubuntu

sdd:
120 GB initially unallocated to be used to install Ubuntu.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Edit 2:

Thankfully Mageia still functions and it's grub still works. Does anyone know how I can add Ubuntu to the Mageia grub?

Edit 3:

Booted to Mageia and just used update-grub. Everything seems to be working fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

During installation of Ubuntu there it will ask you if you want to install Ubuntu alongside or over another installation found.

In your case the Windows 8 will be replaced by the other OS...

[image]